# how to ignore null or blank value while writing to JSON using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json

I'm writing below content to JSON file, I would like to `ignore` the fields which has value `null` or `blank` - in this case I want to ignore `productPrice` and `productRating` fields while writing to JSON file, I'm not much familiar with NodeJS - can someone please help how can I achieve this in NodeJS?

**Please find my code below:**

```
const fs = require('fs');

const params = {
    productID: 'prd323434',
    productName: 'Google',
    productDesc: 'Larum ipsum',
    productPrice: null,
    productRating: '',
    productReview: 'Lorum ipsum'
};

var data = {
    productID: params.productID,
    productName: params.productName,
    productDesc: params.productDesc,
    productPrice: params.productPrice,
    productRating: params.productRating,
    productReview: params.productReview
};

let jsonContent = JSON.stringify(data);
fs.writeFileSync('test.json', jsonContent);

console.log(jsonContent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look like you are just filtering your object for "falsy" values.

So take params, use `Object.entries` on it to get something like this:

```
[
 [productID, 'prd323434'],
 [productName, 'Google'],
 ...
]
```

Use the filter method on the result, destructure each param with `([k,v])`. Then only return it if `v` is "truthy".

```
const data = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(params).filter(([k,v]) => v))
```

Or perhaps in a more readable way:

```
const entries = Object.entries(params)
const filtered = entries.filter(([k,v]) => {
  if (v === null || v === "") {
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}))
const data = Object.fromEntries(filtered)
```